# No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication

Tags: java, spring, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am creating token creation using 'client_credentials' grant type in oauth2 spring app. I am able to create token, but when I go for accessing resource and pass this token in header, getting below exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:227)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.authenticateIfRequired(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:354)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:229)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using spring 4.3.2.RELEASE, spring security 4.1.2.RELEASE and oauth2 2.0.10.RELEASE.

**Updating with config file**

*oauth-security.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd">

<sec:authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider">
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
<bean id="customAuthenticationProvider"
    class="com.XYZ.handler.CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>

<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials/>
    <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager" />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<bean id="requestFactory"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="passwordTokenGranter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter">
    <constructor-arg ref="userAuthenticationManager" />
    <constructor-arg ref="tokenServices" />
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    <constructor-arg ref="requestFactory" />
</bean>

<sec:authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

//endpoints are configured here with respective scopes
//<sec:http />

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    resource-id="oauth2-resource" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<bean id="clientDetails"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.JdbcClientDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="citrus-rest" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.ConsensusBased">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter">
                <property name="throwException" value="false" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="allowIfEqualGrantedDeniedDecisions" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="com.XYZ.XYZDefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="15552000" />
    <property name="refreshTokenValiditySeconds" value="23328000" />
    <property name="tokenEnhancer" ref="tokenEnhancer" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="com.XYZ.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenEnhancer"
    class="com.XYZ.TokenEnhancer">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>
<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="citrus-oauth" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthTXManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<tx:advice id="oauthTXAdvice" transaction-manager="oauthTXManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" isolation="REPEATABLE_READ" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="oauthTokenServiceOperations"
        expression="execution(* org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="oauthTXAdvice" pointcut-ref="oauthTokenServiceOperations" />
</aop:config>
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="TokenServiceOperations"
        expression="execution(* com.XYZ.XYZDefaultTokenServices.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="oauthTXAdvice"
        pointcut-ref="TokenServiceOperations" />
</aop:config>
```

*security-config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans:beans xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd "> 

<!--####################################################################################-->
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"> 
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl"> 
        <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </sec:authentication-provider> 
</sec:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="com.XYZ.PasswordEncoder">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl" class="com.XYZ.UserDetailsServiceImpl">
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Show your security config and spring config

Comment: Share your configuration code in order to best assist with your problem.

Comment: @PrasannaKumar : Updated with config file.

Comment: @koushikR: Please check edited question

Comment: Show web.xml also..and where have u mentioned the intercept urls??..and also stacktrace is only that much...you are missing `caused by` stacktrace...show complete exception